# Method by Action name within nested feature folder hierarchy

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I read about feature folder implementation here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt763233.aspx

I really like the idea to separate by features instead of file types. I'm working on an enhanced solution which allows to build hierarchy of features in unlimited levels.

I created a very simple folder/file organization logic for this. For example:

```
[Feature]
  [Auth]
    [Entity]
      User.cs
      Role.cs
    [Route]
      [Login]
         [Forgot]
            Forgot.cs
            Forgot.cshtml
            ForgotModel.cs
         Login.cs
         Login.cshtml
         LoginModel.cs
      Index.cs
      Index.cshtml
    Auth.cs
```

As you can see everything placed under the top level Feature folder. Within this folder there are specific feature folders (Auth). Under that there is a Route subfolder which contains the hierarchy of all controllers/views.

For the example above I already implemented a custom routing logic which provides me these routes:

```
/Auth
/Auth/Login
/Auth/Login/Forgot
```

It works but I don't know if I did it well or completly wrong. To achieve a custom routing I simply done this:

```
public void Apply(ControllerModel controller)
{
   //From the article I linked before:
   controller.Properties.Add("feature", 
     GetFeatureName(controller.ControllerType));

   //My custom route value implementation:
   controller.Selectors.Clear();

   var routePath = GetRoutePath(controller.ControllerType); //"auth/login/forgot"
   var routeAttr = new RouteAttribute(routePath);
   var selector = new SelectorModel 
     { 
       AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel(routeAttr) 
     };

   controller.Selectors.Add(selector);

}
```

- Is controller.Selectors the good place to apply custom route path?
- Was it really needed to .Clear() before added new?

I didn't find any article about controller.Selectors.

I also like to implement a support for action name to http method conversion where all standard http verb action names (get, post, put, patch, delete) automatically binded to the appropriate http method filter. For example:

```
public class Login : Controller
{
   public IAcionResult Get()
   {
      return View();
   }

   public IAcionResult Post(LoginModel model)
   {
      return Ok()
   }
}
```

I don't want to use [HttpGet] and [HttpPost] attributes everywhere I have only get/post actions. I think there is an official solution for this but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which looks like works well. But I don't really sure what I just done with this:

```
    public class ActionModelConvention : IActionModelConvention
    {
        private static readonly List<String> httpVerbs;

        static ActionModelConvention()
        {
            httpVerbs = new List<String> { "GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE" };
        }

        private readonly ActionParserOptions options;

        public ActionModelConvention(ActionParserOptions options)
        {
            this.options = options;
        }

        public void Apply(ActionModel action)
        {
            var upper = action.ActionName.ToUpper();
            var found = httpVerbs.FirstOrDefault(
                     e => upper.Length >= e.Length &&
                     e == upper.Substring(0, e.Length));

            if (found != null)
            {
                //action.Selectors.Clear(); //no need to clear...I think...

                var constraint = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal //> Internal!
                    .HttpMethodActionConstraint(new String[] { found });

                var selector = new SelectorModel();
                    selector.ActionConstraints.Add(constraint);

                action.Selectors.Add(selector);
            }
        }
```

I don't think it would be a good idea to use anything from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal namespace. But I didn't find other way yet.

Any thoughts?